# Mongodb Query with conjoined data points

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I'm trying to create a query that can pull this information from my database using just the type score when it's less than 70 and when it's of type exam:

```
  {"_id":0,"name":"aimee Zank",
 "scores":[{"score":1.463179736705023,"type":"exam"},      
{"score":11.78273309957772,"type":"quiz"},{"score":35.8740349954354,"type":"homework"}]}
```

I'm not getting any errors and it's turning up blank. Here's the query I'm trying to use:

```
db.students.find({"scores":[{"score":{$lt:70},"type":"exam"}]}).pretty
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you match elements inside array. Use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch) :

```
db.students.find({"scores":{$elemMatch:{score:{$lt:70},type:"exam"}}})
```

**Update**:
OP marked the post as "not answered" and then come with twisted requirement. Going forward, make sure you post a seperate question for your entirely new requirements or **state your problem properly, dont extend it as the time flies**. However, here's the filter query using aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields:{scores:{$filter:{
     input:"$scores",
     as:"score",
     cond:{$and:[{$eq:["$$score.type","exam"]},{$lt:["$$score.score",70]}]} 
   }}}}
])
```

This filters all exams that have `score` less than 70.

Comment: That doesn't filter anything, it just queries the whole database.

Comment: Tell me one thing,  how my query is different from what you did?  How come it query the whole database? It just queries the `students´ collection. This makes no sense to me. Please explain ur problem properly in the question. My answer is based on your question,  not based on your assumptions.

Comment: Also u didnt mention that you wanted to `filter´ and didnt want to hit find query. You just asked why your find query not working and I have corrected that. Your find query also hitting the entire collection and its not different from my query. If you want to use filter operator in the array,  go refer them at mongo docs.